# How to fix IP Whitelist error in URI module of Ansible?

Tags: ansible, uri

I am getting "IP not in white-list!" error when I run below playbook. How can I fix this error?

tasks:

```
- name: Create AD groups
  uri:
    url: https://server.uk.db.com:6001/governance/sims/users/jyotsnaparasjain@db.com/groups
    method: POST
    body: '{"nar":"123456-5", "env_list": ["PROD"], "roles": ["L1"], "approver3": "jyotsnaparasjain@gmail.com"}'
    user: jyotsnaparasjain@gmail.com
    body_format: json
    status_code: 200
    force_basic_auth: yes
    headers:
      X-Auth-Token: "token_comes_here"
    validate_certs: no
  register: create_ad_group

- name: Response of AD Group
  debug:
    var: create_ad_group.json
```

Error:
\"EXCEPTION\": \"IP not in white-list!!\"\n}\n"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this error message is an answer from a remote server. Try to talk to the administrator of the server server.uk.db.com to grant the access for your IP.

Otherwise, to get a better answer, please, provide the full error instead of small excerpt.